Movie from probably 90s or early 2000's about kids in modern times finding a treasure map that leads to an old ship that's on shore
I hope that title's long enough! I used to rent this from my local library when I was a kid (not sure how many times.) 
Date : 90s or early 2000's
Scenes and facts : 

The most memorable scene I can give is at the end where the kids have a sword fight, maybe two, but one was with the old man who lived on the boat. 
I remember a scene at the beginning where the two boys are looking at the map on the computer. 
Maybe there was also a scene where they went to the library. 
I think I remember that they'd get in a lot of trouble, and that there was one scene at their mothers office. 
I should mention that I think the two boys are friends and not siblings. There may have also been a girl, maybe not until the end or something.
I think there was also something about a dad, maybe divorced. Or boyfriend maybe, or love interest. 
I also think I remember the main kid either being a big pirate fan, or being a big history fan. 
The opening scene may have been set in the past with real pirates and it shows what happens with the ship and the map.
Live action, in color, English. I hope this is enough to help you figure out what this movie is! I've been wondering for a while now!


Please format your question to make it more readable. Also, provide additional details like was it an animation movie, in color or black and white, actors, language etc. Visit help center for further details as to how to ask a well received question.

It might be the movie The Lost Treasure of Sawtooth Island (1999)

IMDB

Young man assembles a small offbeat crew to find the mythical pirate
  treasure that's supposedly on the bottom of Lake Michigan and save his
  family from bankruptcy.

traileraddict 

Danny Quinn lives with one great dream....he wants to prove his late
  father was right about a pirate treasure in the depths of Lake
  Michigan.
Everyone opposes Danny's dream, especially his grandfather,
  Ben, a practical old salvage diver who doesn't believe in such
  nonsense. Suddenly everything changes though when Ben has a tragic
  accident during a dive on a local wreck. The bank forecloses on Ben's
  property, and Danny, faced with living in a foster home, runs. That
  night he meets the ghost of Picaroon, who has come to warn Danny about
  a mysterious foe and to help him find the gold.
Danny sets off on his great quest, taking a ragtag crew which includes
  Toby  Weems, a windy old town character, Rufe, Danny's oddball buddy,
  and Smokey Jeanne, a tough Chicago girl. They sail off pursued by
  treasure hunter, Doc Biehler, and his weird wife Mother. After a
  knock-down battle with Doc, who makes off with the treasure map, it's
  Smokey's toughness and support that wins Danny over. Eventually, Danny
  must battle Doc for possession of the map. The final twist is learning
  that Doc's wife, Mother, is the real brains behind Doc's group and a
  master swordfighter. But Picaroon's training pays off and Danny
  defeats Mother to win the treasure.
At the end in an emotional
  farewell, Picaroon returns for one last visit. Then, after seeing the
  treasure, sails off, leaving Danny and his friends jubilant that the
  Quinn family name will be restored and that all debts will be settled.


Trailer
